# How to slowly change direction of the stepper motor with AccelStepper?

Tags: stepper-motor, speed

I know that direction can be changed with

```
.setSpeed(speed);
... //check input
.setSpeed(-speed);
```

I need to slowly decelerate and accelerate backwards, so I have to use

```
.setAcceleration(200);
...
.setMaxSpeed(speed);
... //check input
.setMaxSpeed(-speed);
```

but documentation told that .setMaxSpeed argument Must be > 0.

So how to properly change direction with deceleration? Probably I have to use .moveTo with some very big values

Comment: have you looked at the example code that is included with the library?

Comment: The library defines speed as `steps per second`. It doesn't care about the direction the steps are in. Just like you can't get out of a speeding tickets by always driving in reverse ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested it on real motor, and it works as I want with function .moveTo . Speed slowly changed from +maxSpeed to -maxSpeed acording to Acceleration

```
#define maxSpeed 1000
#define Acceleration 500
............
void setup(){  
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(maxSpeed);
  stepper.setAcceleration(Acceleration);
}
void loop() {
 ............
 if(bDirection!=bDirection_last)
 {
  stepper.moveTo(bDirection?6000000:-6000000);
  ...........
 }
 stepper.run();
}
```